# Provide dynamic value to sql file from sql-maven-plugin

Tags: maven, maven-3

I have set of oracle database view creation script files, which needs schema name as dynamic parameter while getting executed bt maven-sql-plugin. How do I pass this parameter using "sql-maven-plugin".

This is an example :

`CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW MY_VIEW AS SELECT * FROM FROM &SCHEMA_NAME.MY_TABLE`.

Here I want to pass &SCHEMA_NAME from sql-plugin, is it possible to do?

Comment: `&SCHAME_NAME` is sqlplus syntax. You could use properties and filtering to achieve that but you need to replace `&SCHEMA_NAME` with `${SCHEMA_NAME}` ...

Comment: Any link I can refer to achieve this?

Comment: Sure http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html

Comment: Thanks, this worked !